# Creating a PHP switch that switched the stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, switch-statement

I have to make a button on a website that switches the stylesheet(back and forth). I've gotten pretty far that the button is working, however if I'm on another page that the homepage and click on the button it switches back to my homepage :(

I cant really give a jsfiddle for this one so I hope its clear like this.

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
if ($kiescss==1) 
{
    echo "<a href=.?sheet=2>switch</a>";
}
else if ($kiescss==2)
{
    echo "<a href=.?sheet=1>switch</a>";
}
?>
```

The "kiescss" is from another PHP file which includes this:

```
if (empty($_GET['sheet']))
$kiescss=1;
else
$kiescss = $_GET['sheet'];

if (!filter_var($kiescss, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || $kiescss > 2 || $kiescss < 1)
$kiescss=1;
```

Comment: oh, it didnt add my last code: <?php include "switch.inc"; ?>

Comment: you'd have to include the current script name into that link.

Comment: Where does `$kiescss` come from? Input variables do not magically appear in your scripts; unless you are using some... seriously old-school tricks. Why do you not use an actual `switch` statement? It was made for things like this. Are you sure `.?` points to the right path? Using an absolute path would make it less ambiguous as to where it is pointing to. You should also consider quoting the `href` value. It is not strictly necessary, as long as there are no special characters in the URL, but it will most likely cause problems at some point.

Comment: $Kiescss comes from another script I wrote: 

    <?php

if (empty($_GET['sheet']))
    $kiescss=1;
else
    $kiescss = $_GET['sheet'];

if (!filter_var($kiescss, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || $kiescss > 2 || $kiescss < 1)
    $kiescss=1;
    
?>
    
    <link href="style<?php echo $kiescss; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

I really don't understand how to "include the current script" :( I never used PHP and I also havent heard of a switch statement

Comment: We really need to see more of your code. Glad to see that you are using `filter_var`, though. That is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for your link to work, you should change the url of the link. You should echo your path in the href attribute so the link always refer to the page you're on.

Comment: Can you give an example? I really don't know anything about php.. I don't see an URL in my PHP. Should I add one?

Comment: You can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which is a PHP global variable to get the current path. And than you need to change your "<a href=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?sheet=2>switch</a>" so that your link always point toward the current page the user is visiting.

Answer (score 0):

Every page should have the switch script included.

*anypage.php*

```
if (isset($_GET['sheet'])) {
  $sheet = $_GET['sheet'];
} else {
  $sheet = 1 // default
}

include 'header.php'
[...]

// Switch button
if ($sheet == 1) {
  echo "<a href='?sheet=2'>Switch</a>"
} else {
  echo "<a href='?sheet=1'>Switch</a>";
```

*header.php*

```
if ($sheet == 2) {
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=..."
} else {
  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=..." // default
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I fixed it.